# PHP MySQL Query Not Returning Full Set of Desired Results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**I have the following `mysql_query` which I have placed in a PHP variable:**

```
$equalDimensions_query = 
"SELECT 'allEqual' AS COL1,COUNT(*) AS imgCount FROM (
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId FROM primary_images
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images
) AS union_table
WHERE primaryId = $imgId AND imgWidth = $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight = $maxImageHeight
UNION ALL
SELECT 'widthEqual' AS COL1,COUNT(*) AS imgCount FROM (
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId FROM primary_images
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images
) AS union_table
WHERE primaryId = $imgId AND imgWidth = $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight != $maxImageHeight
UNION ALL
SELECT 'heightEqual' AS COL1,COUNT(*) AS imgCount FROM (
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId FROM primary_images  
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images
) AS union_table
WHERE primaryId = $imgId AND imgWidth != $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight = $maxImageHeight";
```

**I am using the following PHP to place the results into *one single* associative array:**

```
$equalDimensions_data = mysql_query($equalDimensions_query) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($equalDimensions_data)) { 
    $cnt[$row['COL1']] = $row['imgCount']; 
}
```

It is suppose to return a set of three arrays with the values of `allEqual` in the first, `widthEqual` in the second, and `heightEqual` in the third (the order does not matter).

**Alas for some reason it is *not* returning `allEqual`:**

```
Array
(
    [heightEqual] => 0
    [widthEqual] => 0
)
```

When I use `print_r` to display the retrieved data in its original 'three array' form, I get the same result of only *two* arrays:

```
Array
(
    [COL1] => heightEqual
    [imgCount] => 0
)
Array
(
    [COL1] => widthEqual
    [imgCount] => 0
)
```

*Yet*, if I use `print_r` *without* the loop as follows:

```
$equalDimensions_data = mysql_query($equalDimensions_query) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());
$equalDimensions_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($equalDimensions_data);

print("<pre>");
print_r($equalDimensions_array);
print("</pre>");
```

I am returned the previously missing `allEqual` array:

```
Array
(
    [COL1] => allEqual
    [imgCount] => 2
)
```

I understand that because of the absence of the `while` loop in the last case, I am only being returned *one* result; But why is it, that in the case of the `while` loop, the `allEqual` result appears to be skipped over? Is it a problem with my code? I appreciate any help you can provide. And I apologize for such a long question; I wanted to be sure I provided as much information as I could.

---

You can download my database schema here: https://files.me.com/stefanmelnychenko/453l4z

Comment: Break the problem in pieces. Run the query directly in a Client so there is no php in the picture. After you make sure the query is okay, you forget the sql it is not in the debugging picture anymore, then php will be easy to debug, at last it's an array matter not something diffuclt.

Comment: how does the $row var change during the while loop? I'd see how it evolves w/ debugger. Or even a var_dump of it as the first thing. If something's wrong with it, it might impact further array construction for you.

Comment: I agree w/ Melsi. Mine is also a suggestion to break the problem in pieces. First find out if the query returns you expected results. Then, try to follow how the $row variable evolves with mysql_fetch_assoc calls. If all is as you expect, then also watch the new array upon each step of its creation.

Comment: @Melsi - Thanks for the advice. I ran the query directly in phpMyAdmin (I think that's what you meant). The query returned everything properly. So I guess the problem is in the PHP. I've never debugged PHP, what would you recommend?

Comment: Yes this is what I meant. I hope you tested the echoed query, I mean copy paste from the browser not coping the query from the code editor. However I am going to give it a try my self (will create the needed tables) and will let you know.

Comment: @Melsi - Would it be helpful if I posted a link to download the database schema? It's not too large at this point. But concerning the test, I did not test the echoed query. How would I do that? Are you meaning just the variables in the query being values, and not variables? Because I did indeed replace the variables with values, if that's what you meant...

Comment: Don't change anything at all, just do that echo $equalDimensions_query="you query as it is";   Then copy the query from the web page on the browser. Yes you can sent the schema, okay!

Comment: And if you do `print_r($cnt[$row['COL1']]);` ?

Comment: @Melsi - I posted the link to my schema at the bottom of my original question, but here it is as well: https://files.me.com/stefanmelnychenko/453l4z

Comment: @Melsi - Oh, and I did as you asked, and cut and pasted the echoed code. It gave the same result as my last test. In other words, it worked perfectly. This again leads me to believe the problem is in the PHP.

Comment: @OhCaN - If i do `print_r($cnt[$row['COL1']]);` it gives me nothing. Again, I'm thinking the problem is in the PHP.

Comment: I understand, it's okay, however I didn't do well too. Both pieces of php code you showed work fine. On the other hand, with a very carefull look (which I didn't do unfortunately cause incorrectly was too focused on sql), in the results shown one could realize the inconsistency and see what the problem is. This is:                                                                                                                               ***

 - **First sql record missing = mysql_fetch was somehow executed**

*** before the while loop causing the mysql pointer to seek to the next record. Bye!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you copy from. You don't change variables or anything in order to copy any errors if any.
[image: sql echoed]

I checked your schemma and everything was fine, this is the php script:

```
<?PHP

// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());

//select database   
mysql_select_db("new_arrivals_imgs") or die(mysql_error());


$imgId=1;
$maxImageHeight=1;
$maxImageWidth=1;

 $equalDimensions_query = 
"SELECT 'allEqual' AS COL1,COUNT(*) AS imgCount FROM (
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId FROM primary_images
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images
) AS union_table
WHERE primaryId = $imgId AND imgWidth = $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight = $maxImageHeight
UNION ALL
SELECT 'widthEqual' AS COL1,COUNT(*) AS imgCount FROM (
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId FROM primary_images
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images
) AS union_table
WHERE primaryId = $imgId AND imgWidth = $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight != $maxImageHeight
UNION ALL
SELECT 'heightEqual' AS COL1,COUNT(*) AS imgCount FROM (
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, imgId AS primaryId FROM primary_images  
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth, primaryId FROM secondary_images
) AS union_table
WHERE primaryId = $imgId AND imgWidth != $maxImageWidth AND imgHeight = $maxImageHeight";

$equalDimensions_data = mysql_query($equalDimensions_query)
 or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($equalDimensions_data)) { 
    $cnt[$row['COL1']] = $row['imgCount']; 
}

print_r($cnt);

?>
```

and this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Already too late for me, bed time now. Happy to answear again when back, bye! I am struggling to think why it works for me and not for you, but... however do check my script exactly as it is and see what differences are there in comparison to yours. Bye!

Comment: Ever feel like a complete moron? I realized (with the help of a very good de-bugging tool called MacGDBp), that when I was switching from using `print_r` to test, and `$cnt[$row['COL1']] = $row['imgCount'];`, I forgot to remove the `$equalDimensions_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($equalDimensions_data);` which was apparently storing, and removing, the first array. I feel awful to have made you go through all that for a stupid mistake on my part. Please accept my apology and thanks for all your help.